# Plotly Express Graphs side by side in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, plotly, plotly-python

I am having a challenge in displaying the Plotly.Express graphs side by side in Jupyter Notebook. It seems the feature is not yet available. Is there a way using **ipywidgets**, we can achieve this? Am trying to use below code where a, b are the graph objects to be shown side by side.

```
import ipywidgets
from ipywidgets import HBox, Layout, widgets
from IPython.display import display
out1=widgets.Output()
out2=widgets.Output()
with out1:
    display.display(a)
with out2:
    display.display(b)
hbox=widgets.HBox([out1,out2])
hbox
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- its straight forward to achieve with `make_subplots()`
- demonstrated by creating traces with **px** and placing them in left / right
- **ipwidgets** is second solution

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import ipywidgets as widgets

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2)
fig_l = px.line(
    pd.DataFrame({"x": np.linspace(1, 100, 300), "y": np.sin(np.linspace(1, 20, 300))}),
    x="x",
    y="y",
)
fig_r = px.bar(
    pd.DataFrame({"x": np.linspace(1, 20, 30), "y": np.cos(np.linspace(1, 20, 30))}),
    x="x",
    y="y",
)
fig.add_trace(
    fig_l.data[0],
    row=1,
    col=1,
)
fig.add_trace(
    fig_r.data[0],
    row=1,
    col=2,
)
fig
```

[image]

#### ipwidgets

```
widgets.HBox(
    [go.FigureWidget(fig_l.data, layout={"width":500, "height":300}), go.FigureWidget(fig_r.data, layout={"height":300})],
)
```

Comment: thanks Rob. The solution worked. with Make subplots, legend is showing at one place for all the sub plots and on the widgets solution. am failing to convert the notebook into a stand alone html page.

Comment: sub plots - it's the way **plotly** works.  One legend for whole figure,  you can place it in different places,  but only one legend.  **ipwidgets** is **jupyter** solution not HTML,  but definition of what they are.  Core capabilities you will need to work out which is best for your final solution ...