# Plotly with Pandas dataframe side by side in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, plotly

There are some questions about how to create [two plotly graphs side-by-side in Jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70639494/plotly-express-graphs-side-by-side-in-jupyter-notebook) or [how to show two pandas dataframes side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35790922/how-to-render-two-pd-dataframes-in-jupyter-notebook-side-by-side). But I would like to display a plotly graph with a pandas dataframe side by side in a Jupyter notebook. Here is some reproducible code for the graph and pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.iris() 
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length")
fig.show()

# Simple pandas dataframe
df[["sepal_length", "species"]].groupby("species").agg(['mean', 'count', 'median', 'min', 'max'])
```

Output:

[image]

Now the output is below each other, but I would like to have them side by side. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to show a plotly graph side by side with a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a subplot and place the table view on the second column. This example should run:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

df = px.data.iris()

specs = [
    [{"type": "xy"}, {"type": "table"}]
]

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=1, 
    cols=2, 
    specs=specs, 
    subplot_titles=[
        "A Scatter Plot", 
        "A DataFrame"
    ]
)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df.index,
    y=df["petal_length"].values
),
row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Table(
    header={"values": df.columns},
    cells={"values": (
        df
        .transpose()
        .values
        .tolist()}
    )
),
row=1, col=2)
fig.update_layout(template="plotly_dark")
fig.show()
```

Produces this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the original poster here posted an updated answer that does what you are looking for using `make_subplots()`:

[Is there a way to use ONE Plotly drop down button to interact with data as well as a plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71296687/8508004)

It does more than you need; however, you should be able to adapt it to remove that and build in your code.